# Enviar variables a controlador/pagina phpmailer

Tags: php, phpmailer

Estoy tratando de generar un email en el que a partir de los datos de una tabla y datos relacionados (nombre de trabajador a partir de la id trabajador ), el punto llega en que tengo un modal donde carga las variables y las envio a la pagina con el codigo de phpmailer. Por lo que observo no carga las variables en post ya que no lo reconoce al despues intentar incluirlo en el contenido (body) del email. como deberia proceder, os paso codigo de ambos, el modal y el de phpmailer (si alguien puede decirme como puedo poner el codigo en dos fracciones lo agradezco ya que no se como ponerlo separado) (en el php mailer pongo *** donde van mi email y pswd)

```
                                <div class="modal-dialog modal-xl">
                                    <div class="modal-content">
                                        <div class="modal-header" style="background-color:gold">
                                            <h5 class="modal-title" id="modal-emailcita" style="color: black;"><i class="bi bi-person-lines-fill"></i>Recon. Médico - <?php echo $citasrm_dato['nombre_tr'] ?> - Detalles</h5>
                                            <button type="button" class="close" style="color:black;" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                            </button>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="modal-body">

                                            <form action="../../app/controllers/reconocimientos/enviar_email.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

                                                <div class="row">

                                                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                                                        <div class="form-group row">
                                                            <label for="nombre_tr" class="col-form-label col-sm-2">Nombre</label>
                                                            <div class="col-sm-8">
                                                                <input type="text" id="" name="nombre_tr" value="<?php echo $citasrm_dato['nombre_tr'] ?>" class="form-control" disabled>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                                                        <div class="form-group row">
                                                            <label for="dni_tr" class="col-form-label col-sm-4">DNI/NIE</label>
                                                            <div class="col-sm-8">
                                                                <input type="text" id="" name="dni_tr" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $citasrm_dato['dni_tr'] ?>" disabled>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>

                                                </div>
                                                
                                        <div class="modal-footer">

                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
                                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="bi bi-envelope-arrow-up"></i></i> Enviar</button>

                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                </form>
                            </div>


---- aqui va la pagina del phpmailer---

 <?php

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require '../emails/Exception.php';
require '../emails/PHPMailer.php';
require '../emails/SMTP.php';

$nombre_tr = $_POST['nombre_tr'];
$dni_tr = $_POST['dni_tr'];


$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

try {
    //Server settings
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;                      //Enable verbose debug output
    $mail->isSMTP();                                            //Send using SMTP
    $mail->Host       = 'smtp.gmail.com';                     //Set the SMTP server to send through
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                                   //Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username   = '****';                     //SMTP username
    $mail->Password   = '****';                               //SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS;            //Enable implicit TLS encryption
    $mail->Port       = 465;                                    //TCP port to connect to; use 587 if you have set `SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS`

    //Recipients
    $mail->setFrom('***', '***');
    $mail->addAddress('***', 'User');     //Add a recipient
    $mail->addAddress('***');               //Name is optional

    //Content
    $mail->isHTML(true);                                  //Set email format to HTML
    $mail->Subject = 'Asunto';
    $mail->Body    = "<html>
    <body>
           <h3>Nombre: $nombre_tr</h3>
        <br>
        <h3>Apellido: $dni_tr</h3>
          </body>
    </html>";

    $mail->send();
    echo 'Email enviado correctamente';
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Error al enviar el email: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
}
```

Comment: cuano publiques preguntas, intenta separar: en que trabajas, que debe hacer el codigo, que es lo que hace y si hay algun error especifico lo muestras... la verdad, no entiendo nada de lo que has argumentado en tu publicacion, puede ser que tenga problemas mas por no saber como se le llaman las cosas a el mismo error.

Comment: en tal caso esto que estas haciendo es una tarea, proyecto personal, trabajo?

Comment: en este caso estoy tratando de realizar un proyecto personal para gestionar las cita de reconocimiento medico y en el momento que creo una nueva solicitud quiero que recoja las variables del trabajador y las mande por email. Por lo que tengo una tabla de aquellas personas que quiero citar y en cada linea de registros hay un boton que activa un modal y recoge todos los datos de la id del trabajador (nombre, dni, edad, etc.) y quiero que los mande a una direccion de correo con phpmailer.

Comment: organizamos los concepto???

Comment: No entiendo lo de organizamos los concepto, pero en todo caso, la primera parte del codigo recoge unas variables y las manda con _POST al codigo de phpmailer, y ahi es cuando intento colocarlas en diferentes partes del post o bien en la direccion de envio y no me reconoce las variables

Comment: quien la recoje?

Comment: como validad que se envia del frontend al backend la variable y como validas que la variable llega al backend para ser usada? necesito que primero puedas responder a esta pregunta para poder continuar, ya que tu publicacion no incluye, ni ejemplo de que probaste ni errores que salgan por pantalla y a las adivinanzas no se puede ayudar... se requiere que hagas DEBUG de tu propio codigo.